# Gulp.src glob match/negate with single line not working

Tags: gulp

I've used this glob pattern for preprocessors in karma config. However, It's not working with gulp.src. What am I doing wrong here?

```
'./app/(modules|shared)/**/!(*spec|*mock).js',
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we need to use {} instead of (), also had to move the ignore part into a separate line...

```
'./app/{modules,shared}/**/*.js',
'!./app/{modules,shared}/**/*{spec,mock}.js',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line with:

```
'./app/+(modules|shared)/**/!(*spec|*mock).js'
```

Note the +